# Submit form with HTML and JS to email

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am using a form for people to submit contact requests for a website. I'm using JS and HTML for this website. I've tried to use mailto but it doesn't actually send anything to my email when I press submit. I don't want to use PHP if I can avoid it since I don't know PHP that well.

Here is my HTML

```
<form method=POST action="mailto:naomikudren@gmail.com" enctype="text/plain">

Company<br>
<input type="text" name="companyname"><br>
Contact Person<br>
<input type="text" name="contactname"><br>
Phone number<br>
<input type="tel" name="phonenumber" min="6" max="15"><br>
Email<br>
<input type="email" name="email"><br>

Message<br>
<input type="textarea" name="message" style='white-space:pre-wrap; height:200px;width:500px;'><br>


<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

I haven't done anything in the JS document for this to work. Do I have to use some sort of command for when submit is pressed in JS or should it be enough to do all this in HTML?

Comment: `mailto` won't actually email. It's just a markup interpreted by the browser as a "email link" and it would (usually) just launch your default mail client and point it at the address assigned to `mailto:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant send email directly using Javascript. For this you have to use php Mailing function, which has a very simple syntax.

```
<?php
// the message
$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg);
?>
```

Comment: should I use <form action="#.php"> and then use that syntax in the php file? Or how do I implement this?

Answer (score 3):

You cant send email directly using Javascript, leave aside HTML.

what you can do is open another window with Mail To option.

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com');
//or with subject using below
window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=body');
```

Otherwise you can do AJAX call to server which sends mail, but that will need PHP or other backend programming.

Comment: Thanks :) I guess I'm going to have to use PHP then for it to work.

Comment: Did you code your own in the end, or use some FOSS?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a server side language to send emails .. You cannot do it using client side language like js. So better use a simple php function to send email. It's not difficult ...

Answer (score 0):

"NO! JavaScript can't email a form! but, there are alternatives to send the form data to an email address.

There is no direct method provided by JavaScript to send the data submitted in the form to an email address.

The main concern for not providing a ‘JavaScript email form’ feature is security."